# Mostrar imagen en simulador AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio

Buenas,

Es mi primera vez en este foro, así si hay algún protocolo y me lo he saltado pido perdón jaja.

Mi duda es que cuando simulo mi app en Android Studio, la imagenes asociadas a los botones no se muestran. Sin embargo, no me aparece ningún error al compilar, simplemente me lleva a una pagina en blanco al apretar el boton.

Gracias de antemano, un saludo.

PD: Aqui teneis el codigo:

De una de las imagenes XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/javi"
    android:id="@+id/imageView6" ></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

De la misma imagen, pero Java:

```
  public class javi extends Activity {
    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.javi);
    }
  }
```

Del codigo Main:
public class MainActivity extends  Activity {

```
//Objetos

private Button boton1, boton2, boton3, boton4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Buscamos los botones en nuestro programa

    boton1 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button);
    boton2 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button2);
    boton3 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button3);
    boton4 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button4);

    //Damos uso a los botones

    boton1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                                  public void onClick(View view) {
                                      mostrarRafa(null);
                                  }
                              }
        );
    boton2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                                  public void onClick(View view) {
                                      mostrarJavi(null);
                                  }
                              }
        );

    boton3.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                                  public void onClick (View view){
                                         mostrarMario(null);
                                  }
                                }
        );

    boton4.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                                  public void onClick(View view) {
                                      mostrarJuanmi(null);
                                  }
                              }
        );

    }

public void mostrarRafa(View view){
    Intent kwh= new Intent(this, rafa. class);
    startActivity(kwh);
}
public void mostrarJavi(View view){
    Intent kwh= new Intent(this, javi. class);
    startActivity(kwh);
}
public void mostrarMario(View view){
    Intent kwh= new Intent(this, mario. class);
    startActivity(kwh);
}
public void mostrarJuanmi(View view){
    Intent kwh= new Intent(this, juanmi. class);
    startActivity(kwh);
}

   }
```

Arreglado, muchisimas gracias a todos. 
Un saludo

Comment: Puedes agregar tu codigo!

Comment: Por favor agrega todo el codigo relevante para poder comprender que puede ser lo que este fallando

Comment: Tienes que dar mas detalles agregando tu código ya que de otra forma existen diferentes causas de lo que comentas.

Comment: Que te hace pensar que es algo con el simulador, diría que en un dispositivo físico se va a comportar igual.

Comment: Agrega todo lo  que puedas, código de tus clases y tus _xml_ de tus _Layouts_, etc. También puedes leer la sección [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para futuras preguntas ;)

Comment: Cambia `app:srcCompat="@drawable/javi"` por `android:src="@drawable/javi"`

Comment: Introduciendo las imágenes en la carpeta drawable de la aplicación y a partir de ImageView ¿está mal?

Comment: Con el cambio me da errores.

- Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

- Error:(7) No resource identifier found for attribute 'scr' in package 'android'

Comment: J. soto Si la respuesta de @Elenasys te ayudó a solucionar tu problema por favor selecciónala como correcta, tiene forma de  " ✓"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He visto cual es el problema, en tu layout estas usando `app:srcCompat` para cargar la imagen, si es así debe usar la clase de compatibilidad [`android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageView.html) :

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/javi"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6">
</android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView>
```

de otra forma usando la clase `ImageView`, debes usar únicamente la propiedad `android:src` para asignar la imagen:

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/javi"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6">
   </ImageView>
```

- En ambos casos, asegura que la imagen especificada se encuentre en realidad dentro del folder `/drawable`

No debes tener problema en cargar la imagen con cualquiera de las dos clases

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: al cambiarlo me surgen varios errores:
 
Con el cambio me da errores. - Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt - Error:(7) No resource identifier found for attribute 'scr' in package 'android' 

Y además, da otro error en el (R.id.button)

Comment: debe ser el namespace, agrega todo el layout y asegura tener la imagen dentro del folder /Drawable.

Comment: Tienes que agregar el ImageView como lo muestro en mi respuesta: <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView ....

Comment: @J.Soto es _src_ y no _scr_ como lo tienes ;)

Comment: @J.Soto como indica x4mp73r , corrige debes tener  android:src (NO android:scr),  si usas ImageView.