# ERROR al compilar mi codigo en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Al compilar mi código **Android**, me esta generando el siguiente error:

> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>    Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:

Este es el **`mainActivity`**:

```
package com.example.eduarceleita.hojadevida;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

La `R.` me sale de color rojo como ven en la imagen

**main_activity.xml**:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:text="Eduar Alfonso Celeita"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/foto"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:contentDescription="" />

<Button
    android:text="Perfil profesional"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:text="Formacion academica"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:text="Experiencia Laboral"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button3" />

<Button
    android:text="Referencias"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button4" />

<Button
    android:text="Idiomas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button5" />
```

Me gustaria saber que es lo que está pasando y porque se genera dicho error por favor ayudenme!!

[image: Error al compilar en android Studio]

Comment: Hola! Como bien sabes, este sitio no se maneja como Yahoo respuestas, en el que las respuestas son basadas en una opinion, ¿Es posible que puedas añadir algo de **codigo**, o bien, puedas darnos mas detalles acerca del error? Para asi poder ayudarte

Comment: package com.example.eduarceleita.hojadevida;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
 El R.layout esa "R" me sale en color rojo

Comment: @EduarCeleita agrega todo el codigo a tu pregunta y no como comentario

Comment: añade el código como texto, no como imagen.

Comment: prueba de hacer un clean y despues rebuild

Comment: No señor no funciona

Comment: Importa _R_, ejemplo `import tuPackage_app.R;`

Comment: Así `import com.example.eduarceleita.hojadevida.R` o `import android.R`  Despés les das un _Clean/Rebuild_.

Comment: Eso siempre pasa cuando tienes un Error en `XML` siempre que estés usando recursos cómo `@drawable` `@string` `@style` entre otros.. de seguro estabas usando un recurso y llegaste cambiar dicho recurso; entonces no puede encontrarlo revisa bien tu código `XML`

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir tu fichero build.gradle?

Comment: @EduarCeleita Eduard, agregué una respuesta, simplemente debes cambiar la propiedad para cargar la imagen, usar  app:src="@drawable/foto"

Answer (score 1):

Cuando la clase `R` se muestra de un color rojo quiere decir que existe algún problema en los recursos.

Para corregir el problema con la clase `R.java`, revisa en los recursos dentro del directorio `/res` probablemente un layout o vista tiene algún tipo de problema.

Recuerda que el layout que carga tu `Activity` se llama `activity_main.xml`

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Al revisar tu layout el problema es facilmente detectable, estas usando la propiedad `app:srcCompat` en tu ImageView, lo cual es incorrecto ya que no usas la clase de compatibilidad `AppCompatImageView`, debes usar la propiedad:

```
 app:src="@drawable/foto"
```

Esto lo puedes ver en la explicación de esta pregunta,, en la cual el usuario tiene un problema similar:

**[Mostrar imagen en simulador AndroidStudio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/32273/mostrar-imagen-en-simulador-androidstudio/32367#32367)**

> He visto cual es el problema, en tu layout estas usando
>   `app:srcCompat` para cargar la imagen, si es así debe usar la clase de
>   compatibilidad `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView` :
>
> ```
>     <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView 
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         app:srcCompat="@drawable/javi"
>         android:id="@+id/imageView6">
> </android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView>
> ```
>
> de otra forma usando la clase `ImageView`, debes usar únicamente la
>   propiedad `android:src` para asignar la imagen:
>
> ```
>     <ImageView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:src="@drawable/javi"
>         android:id="@+id/imageView6">
>    </ImageView>
> ```
>
> - En ambos casos, asegura que la imagen especificada se encuentre en realidad dentro del folder `/drawable`

Answer (score 0):

En tu xml estaba en ImageView con una imagen llamada foto. No se si estas teniendo eso en tu proyecto. **app:srcCompat="@drawable/foto"**

Para compilar en mi maquina le saque la imagen.

Modifique un poco tu xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:text="Eduar Alfonso Celeita"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:contentDescription="" />

    <Button
        android:text="Perfil profesional"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:text="Formacion academica"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:text="Experiencia Laboral"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />

    <Button
        android:text="Referencias"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:text="Idiomas"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button5" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Resultado de la compilación]

Comment: muchas gracias, es decir que la foto es la que me genera el error ?

Comment: La foto o el layer. A mi me daba problemas ambos por eso coloque todo el xml. Por nada. Ya pudiste compilar??

Comment: un momento ya te confirmo

Comment: no señor me sigue generando el mismo error

Comment: Pegaste el xml que agregue?? Cual es el error que te sale?? A mi me funciono. Debe ser un detallecito que falta

Comment: Hace un clean y volve a hacer un build. en caso que te siga dando el error de la referencia de R, hace lo siguiente. Volve a generar un proyecto nuevo y agregale de nuevo todas las clases, recursos, xmls, etc. Y ahí ejecuta. A mi me paso muchas veces el problema que te esta ocurriendo. Y así solucionaba. De alguna manera el compilador esta dando problemas con la referencia. Avisame así solucionamos de una vez este problema para que sigas trabajando.

Comment: listo gracias ya le confirmo

Comment: llevo todo este mes haciendo el mismo proceso, hago un nuevo proyecto pero sigue el mismo bendito error, es la bendita referencia .R

Comment: Entonces, crea un nuevo proyecto. Compila. Luego reemplaza tu xml. Compila, y or ultimo copia todos los archivos. Compila

Comment: listo, vamos a ver

Comment: listo si señor, hice otro proyecto y metí todo lo que me dijo y hasta el momento me compilo sin errores. Pero dado el caso que se repita que puede estar pasando porque se genera ese error?

Comment: no creo que mas tengas problemas. Eso a mi me ocurría solamente cuando modificaba muchísimo las referencias. Una vez, o dos veces nomas me paso eso. Si llegaste a solucionar, podrías marcar como solucionado. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Algunas veces por algún motivo que aun no encuentro Android Studio no importa la clase R, por ese motivo te sale en color rojo, para solucionar ese error intenta mirando los imports en tu clase MainActivity, si no ves la Clase R importada intenta agregarla manualmente así:

```
import com.example.eduarceleita.hojadevida.R;
```

A mi me ha pasado un par de veces.

Saludos.